# How to change Label Value using javascript

Tags: javascript, label

I want to change the label value from '0' to 'thanks' in below label, on checkbox click event.

```
<input type="hidden" name="label206451" value="0" />
<label for="txt206451" class="swatch_text" >Chestnut Leather</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="field206451" class="swatch_check" id="txt206451" value="SELECTED"/>
```

The Javascript is as below.

```
var cb = document.getElementById('field206451');
var label = document.getElementById('label206451');
cb.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
    if(cb.checked){
        label.value='Thanks';
    }else{
        label.value='0';
    }
},false);
```

But this is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're taking `name` in `document.getElementById()` Your `cb` should be `txt206451` 
(*ID Attribute*) not  `name` attribute.

**Or**

You can have it by [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

```
var cb = document.getElementsByName('field206451')[0]; // First one
```

**OR**

```
var cb = document.getElementById('txt206451');
```

And for setting values into hidden use [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) like following

```
var cb = document.getElementById('txt206451');
var label = document.getElementsByName('label206451')[0]; // Get the first one of index
console.log(label);
cb.addEventListener('change', function (evt) { // use change here. not neccessarily
    if (this.checked) {
        label.value = 'Thanks'
    } else {
        label.value = '0'
    }
}, false);
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dW7qL/2/)

Comment: I have added an id to my hidden lavel Id="xyz" and I have changed my javascript to, 
var cb = document.getElementById('txt422743');
var label = document.getElementById('xyz');
Stull not working?

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee Did you go through the answer, Check in fiddle again!

Answer (score 14):

very simple

```
$('#label-ID').text("label value which you want to set");
```

Comment: It's jquery not Javascript.

Answer (score 10):

This will work in *Chrome*

```
// get your input
var input = document.getElementById('txt206451');
// get it's (first) label
var label = input.labels[0];
// change it's content
label.textContent = 'thanks'
```

But after looking, [*labels* doesn't seem to be widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Browser_compatibility)..

---

You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
// get txt206451's (first) label
var label = document.querySelector('label[for="txt206451"]');
// change it's content
label.textContent = 'thanks'
```

Answer (score 2):

hope this help someone else : 
use innerHTML  for using label object.

```
  document.getElementById('lableObject').innerHTML = res.FullName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

use an `id` for hidden field and use id of `checkbox` in javascript.

and change the `ClientIDMode="static"` too

```
<input type="hidden" ClientIDMode="static" id="label1" name="label206451" value="0" />

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var cb = document.getElementById('txt206451');
    var label = document.getElementById('label1');
    cb.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
    if(cb.checked){
        label.value='Thanks'
    }else{
        label.value='0'
    }
    },false);
    </script>
```

Comment: I have added an id to my hidden lavel Id="xyz" and I have changed my javascript to, 
var cb = document.getElementById('txt422743');
var label = document.getElementById('xyz');
Stull not working?

Comment: @SheikhSiddiquee:did you changed the ClientIDMode ??

Answer (score 1):

Based off your code, i created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/uwr8t/5/)

You need to use

```
var cb = document.getElementsByName('field206451')[0];
var label = document.getElementsByName('label206451')[0];
```

if you want to use name attributes then you have to take the index since it is a list of items, not just a single one.  Everything else worked good.